# Measure power consumption of an electric heater

Tags: smart-plugs, power-consumption

I want to measure / monitor power consumption of an electric heater which is connected to a standard power outlet.

There are several meters on the market, however all I found could show only current consumption and total consumption since reset.
I want to somehow access raw measurement (e.g. daily / hourly data)

I found some smart plugs which can also measure consumption, like e.g. this one: https://www.hama.com/00176565/hama-wlan-socket-consumption-measurement-without-hub-f-voice-and-app-control.
As it can be controlled via an app, I hoped I can also access raw results, however unfortunately also this one can show only current consumption and monthly total of current month (confirmed by Hama customer service).

Is there any device on the market which can measure and store raw data.

I live in Hungary, so getting with Hungarian plug would be great.

Comment: Check out https://www.pcmag.com/reviews/eyedro-ebwem1-business-electricity-monitor and https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00XTU9RF2/ref=cm_sw_em_r_mt_dp_86YW4JQAMC7C057ZQVZ8   Let us know what you found out.